# How to dynamically limit folders of media file to be installed ?

Tags: install4j

My media file contains three folders, of which, I want to have only one of those to be installed on user’s machine based on his selection. 
One quick and dirty fix for this is to install all the three folders onto the user machine and then delete two of the unwanted ones. This is additional work and users might not like this. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

That's what installation components are for. You can select them programmatically like this:

```
context.getInstallationComponentById("123").setSelected(true)
```

You can configure installation components on the Files->Installation components step.

Comment: This approach works, thanks for your help. A followup question - User won't be allowed to select components. If showing "installation components" screen mandatory?

Comment: No, you don't have to add the "Installation components" screen to work with installation components